# Plot all pairs of variables in R data frame based on column type

Tags: r

I’m fairly sure I saw a package that did this, but I cannot find its name in my notes.

This package produces a plot for each pair of variables in a data frame, but chooses the plot based on the columns’ types. So, two numeric variables would produce a scatterplot. A numeric y and categorical x would produce side-by-side box plots. Like that. It’s this multiple column type ability that distinguishes it from the packages I can find by Googling.

Perhaps I should say that I’m certain I saw it, and didn’t see a bunch of surrounding code with loops or purr calls looping over the data, so I’m guessing there was a package that did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably thinking of `GGally::ggpairs`:

```r
library(GGally)

ggpairs(iris)
```

[image]